# what is an asymtotic test in hypothesis testing

Tags: probability, statistics

In my math homework I have a question:

Question 1: Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be iid random variables with pdf
$f(x; θ) = (\theta + 1)x^{\theta}
, 0 < x < 1, \theta > −1$

Using the following sample data to conduct an asymptotic test to test
the hypothesis $H_0 : θ = 0.5$ vs $H_1 : \theta \neq 0.5$

[lots of numeric data]

I know how to check type 1 error and type 2 error but what is an asymptotic test? can I have an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it means the use of a central limit theorem, often in the sense that a quantity $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{i=1}^NX_i$$ converges, as $N\to\infty$ ( 
$N$= number of observations), in distribution to a normal distribution provided that the $X_i$ have finite variance and are independent and identically distributed (side note, these are sufficient conditions, the central limit theorem holds under more general conditions).

I would proceed as follows. First, derive an estimator for $\theta$ as a function of the observations (since we are given a pdf $f$ I would go for maximum likelihood). Then, check if the central limit theorem applies. And if so, assume a normal distribution for the estimator under the null hypothesis (meaning you derive the mean and variance of that normal distribution supposing $\theta=0.5$) in order construct a confidence interval for $\theta$.

Finally, the test is: reject the Null if the observed estimate for $\theta$ lies outside the interval.

Side note, since we are given $f$ we could compute the exact distribution for the estimator instead of assuming that $N$ is large enough for the central limit distribution to be a good approximation....but often this "exact" distribution is hard to derive.